# How to append to an array after cherry picking keys of another using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an existing array of objects

```
const oldData = [
  {'one': 1, 'two': 2},
  {'one': 3, 'two': 4}
];
```

I have a new array of objects:

```
const newData = [
  {'three': 5, 'two': 6, 'one': 7},
  {'five': 8, 'one': 9, 'two': 10}, 
];
```

I have an array containing object props I want to extract (this is a variable)

```
const columnMeta = ['one', 'two'];
```

I'd like to create a composable, reusable function using Ramda. This function should extract only the chosen *columnMeta* properties of newArray and append that with whatever that existed in oldArray

The following works but seems a tad bit too verbose (and hardly reusable..)

```
// simple enough, join two arrays using the spread operator
const appendData = curry((curr, prev) => [...prev, ...curr]);

// get a subset of an object, given an array of keys
const extractByColumnMeta = curry((k, obj) => zipObj(k, props(k)(obj)));

// create a composable function that takes an array of keys
const mapDataByColumns = compose(map, extractByColumnMeta)(columnMeta);

// compose a new function that would take a the newData & oldData
const mergeDataAfterMap = compose(appendData, mapDataByColumns);

// works, but I'm sure I can do better :)
mergeDataAfterMap(newData)(oldData);

// => [{one: 1, two: 2}, {one: 3, two: 4}, {one: 7, two: 6}, {one: 9, two: 10}]
```

Non ramda way

```js
const oldData = [
  {'one': 1, 'two': 2},
  {'one': 3, 'two': 4}
];

const newData = [
  {'three': 5, 'two': 6, 'one': 7},
  {'five': 8, 'one': 9, 'two': 10}, 
];

const columnMeta = ['one', 'two'];


const mapDataToColumns = (fields, oldData, newData) => {
    // a new array. anything in oldData is overwritten
    return [...oldData, ...newData.map(row => {
        // reduce to return only wanted keys
        return fields.reduce((acc, field) => {
          // add to accumulator or return
          return row.hasOwnProperty(field) 
            ? {...acc, [field]:row[field]}
            : acc;
        }, {});
    })];
}

console.log(mapDataToColumns(columnMeta, oldData, newData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon @ScottSauyet's answer and comments to @naomik's answer, I came up with this:

```
const pickAndMerge = compose(chain, project);
```

And then it's simply,

```js
const oldData = [
  {'one': 1, 'two': 2},
  {'one': 3, 'two': 4}
];

const newData = [
  {'three': 5, 'two': 6, 'one': 7},
  {'five': 8, 'one': 9, 'two': 10}, 
];

const columnMeta = ['one', 'two'];

const pickAndMerge = R.compose(R.chain, R.project);

console.log(pickAndMerge(columnMeta)([oldData, newData]));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.20.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
const mergeSelectAttr = R.curry((oldData, columnMeta, newData) => 
  R.compose(
    R.concat(oldData), 
    R.map(R.pick(columnMeta))
  )(newData) 
)
```

[Ramda fiddle](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20oldData%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%27one%27%3A%201%2C%20%27two%27%3A%202%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%27one%27%3A%203%2C%20%27two%27%3A%204%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20newData%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%27three%27%3A%205%2C%20%27two%27%3A%206%2C%20%27one%27%3A%207%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%27five%27%3A%208%2C%20%27one%27%3A%209%2C%20%27two%27%3A%2010%7D%2C%20%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20columnMeta%20%3D%20%5B%27one%27%2C%20%27two%27%5D%3B%0A%0A%0A%0Aconst%20mergeSelectAttr%20%3D%20curry%28%28oldData%2C%20columnMeta%2C%20newData%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20compose%28concat%28oldData%29%2C%20map%28pick%28columnMeta%29%29%29%28newData%29%20%0A%29%0A%0AmergeSelectAttr%28oldData%2C%20columnMeta%2C%20newData%29)

I would say this yields to a more flexible api than the current answers, you may call it as per your convenience:

- `mergeSelectAttr(oldData, columnMeta, newData)`
- `mergeSelectAttr(oldData)(columnMeta, newData)`
- `mergeSelectAttr(oldData, columnMeta)(newData)`

One major advantage you get it with this solution would work even if you get your `newData` at a later stage, say from an api call / DB result, it would still work great due to currying. You can of course also change the order of `oldData` and `columnMeta` depending on what you are getting first

Eg:

```
// You have olData and coulmnMeta now, but not newData:
const merger = mergeSelectAttr(oldData, columnMeta)
    .
    .
    .
    .
// A little while later, when you have access to newData:

const finalValue = merger(newData)
```

Comment: Thanks, this one's great too!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compose `R.pick` with `R.concat`, but in a somewhat tricky way. You're trying to compose a unary function, `R.pick(columnMenta)`, with a binary function, `R.concat`.

```
const compose2 = R.compose(R.compose, R.compose)

const foo = compose2(R.map(R.pick(['one', 'two'])), R.concat)

console.log(foo(oldData, newData))
// => [{"one":1,"two":2},{"one":3,"two":4},{"one":7,"two":6}, {"one":9,"two":10}]
```

The arbitrary limitation of two inputs makes this a little weak tho, and most people don't like `compose2` trickery. What if you had several lists of input data and you wanted to combine them in a sensible way? Enter `R.chain` …

```
const foo = R.chain(R.map(R.pick(['one', 'two'])))

console.log(foo([oldData, newData, oldData]))
// => [{"one":1,"two":2},{"one":3,"two":4},{"one":7,"two":6},{"one":9,"two":10},{"one":1,"two":2},{"one":3,"two":4}]
```

Note `foo` now expects an *array* of inputs which effectively allows you to combine as many data sets as you need

---

OK, it seems you also want the `columnMeta` to be an input to the function. It will be easiest if we adapt the latter answer

```
const foo = R.curry((columns, xxs) =>
  R.chain(R.map(R.pick(columns)), xxs))

console.log(foo(['one'], [oldData, newData, oldData]))
// => [{"one":1},{"one":3},{"one":7},{"one":9},{"one":1},{"one":3}]

console.log(foo(['two'], [oldData, newData, oldData]))
// => [{"two":2},{"two":4},{"two":6},{"two":10},{"two":2},{"two":4}]

console.log(foo(['one', 'two'], [oldData, newData, oldData]))
// => [{"one":1,"two":2},{"one":3,"two":4},{"one":7,"two":6},{"one":9,"two":10},{"one":1,"two":2},{"one":3,"two":4}]
```

Comment: Okay, but what if the keys are a variable? (the inner array)

Comment: You can define `let columnMeta = ['one', 'two']` and then compose using `R.pick(columnMeta)`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Actually, not quite. I was looking for a function that will take in the `['one', 'two']` and the datasets as inputs. Updated the question with another example...

Comment: @JasonJ.Nathan, ok i included a way for you to include the columns as an argument to the function

Comment: Note that you can use `R.chain` in place of the `flatMap` above.  And you can use `R.project(...)` in place of `R.map(R.pick(...))`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind this API:

```
mergeAndPick(columnMeta, [oldData, newData]);
//=> [{"one": 1, "two": 2}, {"one": 3, "two": 4}, 
//    {"one": 7, "two": 6}, {"one": 9, "two": 10}]
```

Then you can write it simply like this:

```
const mergeAndPick = R.useWith(R.project, [R.identity, R.unnest]);
```

If you really want this:

```
mergeDataAfterMap(columnMeta, oldData, newData);
//=> [{"one": 1, "two": 2}, {"one": 3, "two": 4}, 
//    {"one": 7, "two": 6}, {"one": 9, "two": 10}]
```

Then you could build it on top of the above.

```
const mergeDataAfterMap = (columnMeta, oldData, newData) => 
    mergeAndPick(columnMeta, [oldData, newData]);
```

But the first one is more flexible, allowing you to specify any number of lists to combine.

This is built on top of a fairly unusual Ramda function, [`useWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith), which makes it easier to combine functions in a points-free manner.  In the days of ES6, it's less of an obvious advantage, and that could be rewritten as

```
const mergeAndPick = R.curry((columnMeta, lists) => 
    R.project(columnMeta, R.unnest(lists)));
```

You can see all this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20oldData%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%27one%27%3A%201%2C%20%27two%27%3A%202%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%27one%27%3A%203%2C%20%27two%27%3A%204%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20newData%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%27three%27%3A%205%2C%20%27two%27%3A%206%2C%20%27one%27%3A%207%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%27five%27%3A%208%2C%20%27one%27%3A%209%2C%20%27two%27%3A%2010%7D%2C%20%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20columnMeta%20%3D%20%5B%27one%27%2C%20%27two%27%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mergeAndPick%20%3D%20R.useWith%28R.project%2C%20%5BR.identity%2C%20R.unnest%5D%29%3B%0A%0AmergeAndPick%28columnMeta%2C%20%5BoldData%2C%20newData%5D%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%7B%22one%22%3A%201%2C%20%22two%22%3A%202%7D%2C%20%7B%22one%22%3A%203%2C%20%22two%22%3A%204%7D%2C%20%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%7B%22one%22%3A%207%2C%20%22two%22%3A%206%7D%2C%20%7B%22one%22%3A%209%2C%20%22two%22%3A%2010%7D%5D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20mergeDataAfterMap%20%3D%20%28columnMeta%2C%20oldData%2C%20newData%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20mergeAndPick%28columnMeta%2C%20%5BoldData%2C%20newData%5D%29%3B%0A%0AmergeDataAfterMap%28columnMeta%2C%20oldData%2C%20newData%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5B%7B%22one%22%3A%201%2C%20%22two%22%3A%202%7D%2C%20%7B%22one%22%3A%203%2C%20%22two%22%3A%204%7D%2C%20%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%7B%22one%22%3A%207%2C%20%22two%22%3A%206%7D%2C%20%7B%22one%22%3A%209%2C%20%22two%22%3A%2010%7D%5D%0A)**.

Comment: Thanks @scott, I really intended to build your first suggestion exactly, where I can create a curried `f = mergeAndPick(columnMeta)` because I get `columnMeta` first. Then I can simply call `f([oldData, newData])`;

I eventually built it with the accepted answer. How would you test the performance of such functions to see which combo is better to use (especially when dealing with large lists)

Comment: I built upon your comments and suggestions and came up with `const pickAndMerge = compose(chain, project);` Then it's simply `pickAndMerge(columnMeta)([oldData, newData]);`. Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Nice final implementation!  I don't know how you would test for performance except through usual benchmarking techniques.  It looks as though http://jsperf.com is finally back up, so that's probably a good way to go, or perhaps you could use its underlying tool, Benchmark.js